# Tratamento de Xml com ASPNET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, xdocument

Estou trabalhando com upload de `Xml` utilizando o `ASPNET MVC Core`, recebo no `controller` o arquivo dessa maneira:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile param)
{
}
```

porem preciso efetuar uma verificação nele antes de terminar o código e efetuar o upload. Meu problema esta sendo ler o arquivo através do `XDocument`, pois o mesmo não aceita esse tipo de elemento que esta chegando.

***Dessa forma:***

```
var dataXml = XDocument.Load(param)
                      .Descendants("ide")
                      .First()
                      .Element("dhEmi")
                      .Value;
```

***Formulário de envio do arquivo:***

```
<form role="form" asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="id" id="id"  multiple />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Já tentei converter para `string` e outros meios porem nenhum sucesso e alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta uma amostra do XML para ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: Boa Tarde Pagotti, como dito a questão não é com o xml e sim com a leitura pelo XDocument que não aceita a forma que recebo o arquivo no controller, mas de qualquer forma é um xml simples de NFE preciso efetuar a leitura da data de emissão.

Comment: Ok. Se você usar `param.OpenReadStream()` no `Load` não funca?

Comment: Vou tentar e te falo essa opção ainda não testei

Comment: Como está seu formulário, pode disponibilizar?

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza melhor você adicionar a tag c# na sua pergunta, vai facilitar achar pessoas que possam te ajudar.

Comment: @Pagotti o OpenReadStream é reconhecido porem não é aceito para efetuar consultar no xml utilizano linq segue o código:

 var dataXml = XDocument.Load(xml.OpenReadStream())
                          .Descendants("ide")
                          .First()
                          .Element("dhEmi")
                          .Value;

Comment: @VirgilioNovic meu formulário é simples, não utilizei nada diferente segue adicionei o código no post

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza eu fiz a solução é que você está fazendo errado em alguns pontos então eu fiz dois exemplos na resposta, se pode utilizar qualquer um dos dois refletindo no seu ai... !!!

Answer (score 3):

No novo modelo de desenvolvimento [ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/), se utiliza a `Interface` [IFormFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile) que tem a responsabilidade de trabalhar com as `input` do tipo `file`.

O problema que está acontecendo é que o valor deveria ser uma **lista** e não **1** elemento, porque a sua configuração do formulário no `input` está com `multiple`, ***exemplo***: `List<IFormFile>`.

***Exemplo básico:***

***Html***

```
<form role="form" asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="id" id="id"  multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

***Controller***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> id)
```

sendo um fator também muito importante o nome do `input` é o mesmo nome colocado no paramento que vai receber os arquivos, exemplo, você colocou `id` no nome do `input` deve seguir o mesmo nome para o paramento do `controller`.

### Como você vai receber os valores sendo que a sua configuração foi em uma lista?

Montei um exemplo minimo para exemplificar isso, onde esse `input` pode enviar múltiplos arquivos para o `controller`:

***Xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <cliente>
    <id>1</id>
    <nome>stackoverflow</nome>
  </cliente>
</root>
```

***Html***

```
<form role="form" asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="id" id="id" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

***Controller***

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> id)
{    
    if (Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
    {
        foreach (var formFile in id)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    formFile.CopyTo(str);
                    str.Position = 0;
                    var xml = (from x in XDocument.Load(str).
                        Descendants("cliente")
                              let _id = x.Element("id").Value
                              let _nm = x.Element("nome").Value
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = _id,
                                  Nome = _nm
                              })
                              .FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }  
    return View();
}
```

No caso exemplo eu enviei apenas um, mas, com o mesmo layout de `Xml` se pode enviar vários, se assim preferir.

---

#### Vale lembrar que se for apenas 1 arquivo por vez é só tirar a parte da coleção da seguinte forma:

***Xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <cliente>
    <id>1</id>
    <nome>stackoverflow</nome>
  </cliente>
</root>
```

***Html***

```
<form role="form" asp-action="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="id" id="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

***Controller***

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile id)
{    
    if (Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
    {                
        if (id.Length > 0)
        {
            using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await id.CopyToAsync(str);
                str.Position = 0;
                var xml = (from x in XDocument.Load(str).
                    Descendants("cliente")
                            let _id = x.Element("id").Value
                            let _nm = x.Element("nome").Value
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = _id,
                                Nome = _nm
                            })
                            .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }               
    }  
    return View();
}
```

ou seja, no `input` tire a configuração `multiple` e no `controller` deixe somente a interface [IFormFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile)

***Referencias***

- [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)
- [IFormFile Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile)
- [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/)